# Change TEMP Path in PHP at run time

Tags: php

I am writing code for uploading file  on server. I have shared hosting services with windows. when I am using this function:

```
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"./admin/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

I am getting error like I can not access temp folder. So I decided to change temp folder location. But I am unable to do this. Can any one help me for change the temp path at run time so I can store file in temp folder.....

Comment: Please give us the exact error message.

Comment: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\windows\Temp\phpFC50.tmp' to '/upload/MA_BA000001_BLU_thumb.jpg

Comment: It says that it's unable to *move to*, not that there's necessarily anything wrong with your temp directory. Are you sure the *target* directory is okay? Have you tried a different target? Maybe tried with an *absolute* path instead of a relative one?

Comment: There is no problem with the tmp folder but with /upload, normally it should be something like ./upload or C:\windows\.....\upload (try to use the root path)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding to .htaccess:

```
php_value upload_tmp_dir "path"
```

Comment: That doesn't help at runtime, the file is already stored in the temp directory at that time.

Comment: yup i used that function like ini_set("upload_tmp_dir", "path");echo $path = sys_get_temp_dir();
echo $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; Getting same temp path like C:\windows\Temp..... not working

Comment: @Deep: PHP manual reports permission issues if you upload to c:/windows/temp
http://php.net/manual/it/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: You can't set it "before uploading the file". You need to set it in an .htaccess file or the php.ini. The above code will never work under any circumstances.

Comment: @deep, try using the full path in your  move_uploaded_file. It looks like you're trying to write on a unix-style path (may or may not give you issues on windows)... Also double check all the folders exist